# AnimatedImage (AvaloniaUI): ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource cann not access files on /Assets

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to use [AnimatedImage](https://github.com/whistyun/AnimatedImage) for AvaloniaUI, but can not resolve fixed gif path.
To reproduce please download the Code of [AnimatedImage](https://github.com/whistyun/AnimatedImage) (Demo) and change the DemoForAvaloniaUI/MainWindow.axaml line 34 from:
`anim:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding SelectedSource.Source}"`
to: `anim:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="avares://DemoForAvaloniaUI/Assets/working.gif"`

I get Error: `Invalid value for Property 'AnimatedSource': 'avares://DemoForAvaloniaUI/Assets/working.gif'`

The file exists, is part of the demo.

Have anyone got this to work?